# I want to manually compile an Android project, but I have no idea how to use Ant

Tags: android, ant

I am having trouble getting one of my Android projects under Eclipse to run correctly in the emulator, so I am seeing if manually compiling it will work. I have gone through the steps of performing `android update project`, but I am now at a loss with using Ant, especially since it seems that half of what Ant does is done with certain build scripts located in the Android SDK directory. How do I exclude files/directories and include libraries using Ant?

Also, what's a good resource that I could use as a tutorial for Ant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- [Official Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-cmdline.html)
- [Ant Android](http://code.google.com/p/autoandroid/wiki/AndroidAnt)
- [This blogs post](http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/06/using-ant-to-automate-building-android.html) on ant builds on android
- [Linux magazine article](http://www.linux-mag.com/id/7667/)
- [moar](http://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/11/13/hello-world-using-ant-for-googles-android-platform/) [blogs](http://www.alittlemadness.com/2010/05/31/setting-up-an-android-project-build/)