# How to build apk without eclipse or Modify the apk building with a config file?

Tags: android, apk

I want to build an apk with some large configuration from a xml file.
I want to know if there is any method that can control the building process of apk or is there any way to create apk from our source with a little bit of modification on our source based on our config xml file.Or any other way to build apk file
**I don't want to read my config file each and every time when the app run ,I want to include the change in application itself**

All Suggestions,Comments,Answers,Ideas are Welcome
Thanks in advance.....

Comment: Can you explain  **little bit of modification on our source based on our config file**. Or may be elaborate on what do you want to achieve because it is not clear.

Comment: Hi Abhilasha, Thanks for d reply, I will try to explain .. Suppose I have two clients and i can deliver my app for both of them with a little bit of customization or configuration I will get this customization details as a xml file .What i want is create my build for each customer based on this xml . Not to include the xml in app Means I want to override the default building of apk by eclipse with the config details in xml.  you are welcome to  present any ideas, Thanks again for you valuable time....

Comment: Basically, you can not without kind of a precompiler. First, because you want to (you WANT TO) have different namespaces of your packages. Means, you need to touch every single file of your source. Then, I guess you not only want to change java source files, but also ressource files. There is no ready-to-use solution for your very specific task using xml to "reconfigure" your source tree. You have to go on an build such tool by yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to manually build your application :

First off, you should really understand the [build process](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/index.html), if you don't.

> If you are developing in Eclipse, the ADT plugin incrementally builds
>   your project as you make changes to the source code. Eclipse outputs
>   an .apk file automatically to the bin folder of the project, so you do
>   not have to do anything extra to generate the .apk.
>
> If you are developing in a non-Eclipse environment, you can build your
>   project with the generated build.xml Ant file that is in the project
>   directory. The Ant file calls targets that automatically call the
>   build tools for you.

Once you understand the build process, you can start off by learning the commands to perform the various steps involved in building. [The documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-cmdline.html) talks about the various commands you can use.

This [Tutorial](http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/06/using-ant-to-automate-building-android.html) on `Ant` takes you from start to finish on how to perform a custom build.

A few more tutorials:

- [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html)
- http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBuildAnt/article.html
- http://code.google.com/p/autoandroid/wiki/AndroidAnt
- http://www.linux-mag.com/id/7667/
- http://www.alittlemadness.com/2010/05/31/setting-up-an-android-project-build/

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Apache Ant tool. It allows you to build your application through commands instead of with Eclipse.

You can look at the question asked and the answer given in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6529087/i-want-to-manually-compile-an-android-project-but-i-have-no-idea-how-to-use-ant).

Answer (score 1):

I use Maven. It's VERY hard to configure but is the best if you work in a team.

Comment: Hi can you pls provide some more details about the configuration or any helpful links or tutorails

Comment: Internet is full of it. Take a look http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/GettingStarted