# generating a large number of apk's

Tags: android, apk

I have an app and I want to generate about 50 versions of it. Every version with a little differences.

It's some sort of a news app that need to have a lot of version according to the country it's in and some other things.

I am using one main library and all of the `"projects"` are using this library while adding their own stuff.

Is there a way to generate all of the 50 apk's without going one by one using eclipse?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Understanding the build process is essential if you want to create multiple builds of your apk.

Use can Use Ant to [Automate Building Android Applications](http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/06/using-ant-to-automate-building-android.html)
..

I think you should **[refer this as well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11483543/2345913)**